# Schedule in portuguese-Brazil - Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Well, my problem is very simple but i don't know how to solve: How can i translate my schedule component to portuguese-brazil ? I.E : Change "Monday" to "Segunda-Feira" and others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Components like calendar and schedule uses a shared PrimeFaces.locales property to display labels.

So you can add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
PrimeFaces.locales['pt'] = {
            closeText: 'Fechar',
            prevText: 'Anterior',
            nextText: 'Próximo',
            currentText: 'Começo',
            monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun', 'Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Des'],
            dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb'],
            dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S'],
            weekHeader: 'Semana',
            firstDay: 1,
            isRTL: false,
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            yearSuffix: '',
            timeOnlyTitle: 'Só Horas',
            timeText: 'Tempo',
            hourText: 'Hora',
            minuteText: 'Minuto',
            secondText: 'Segundo',
            currentText: 'Data Atual',
            ampm: false,
            month: 'Mês',
            week: 'Semana',
            day: 'Dia',
            allDayText : 'Todo Dia'
        };
</script>
```

And then use the locale attribute on the schedule component:

```
 <p:schedule value="#{scheduleController.eventModel}" locale="pt" />
```

For more read:

[wiki/PrimeFacesLocales](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/PrimeFacesLocales)

[Primefaces Schedule Turkish example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/scheduleLocale.jsf;jsessionid=1upwg5rsxxtu0ywmynlchdz1w)